# Pass information from JavaScript to AutoIt

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, web, autoit

Is there a way I can connect JavaScript with AutoIt such that JavaScript passes data (and parameters to work on) to AutoIt.

Actually I am getting mouse coordinates on a webpage using JavaScript. Now I want to pass those mouse coordinates dynamically to an AutoIt script.

Initially I thought of saving a txt file dynamically with JavaScript and reading it from AutoIt. But as you know, you cannot save a txt file using client-side JavaScript (or jQuery).

Kindly suggest a workaround to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by attaching to the browser window.
That way, autoit can "see" or manipulate everything on the page.

Take a look at the [Chrome UDF](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/154439-chrome-udf/) or [IE UDF](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/13398-internet-explorer-automation-udf-library/)

Comment: I can install AutoIt extension but cannot enable it because it is not available on Chrome Web Store. Any ideas @Milos?

Comment: Maybe use IE instead?

Comment: Well I have to do a ton of things like WebGL and other stuff. IE? Meh.

Comment: IE automation with autoit is by far the most complete browser automation and easiest. No extension or any external "helper" needed in order to manipulate the page. Full help support in AutoIt Help File for every function on IE UDF.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to install a local web server, then pass any data from javascript to the local web server over HTTP, execing AutoIt in a CGI script (or similar) on the web server.

Just be careful how you setup the web server, disallow or firewall out remote connections, because you probably don't want other computers to exec your AutoIt scripts.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you want to pass javascript returned coordinates to AutoIT, I'm assuming it's because you want to perform some action on them that only AutoIT can assist you with.
This tallies with what the author of this little UDF envisioned when he said

> "I wondered if it was possible to "insert" jQuery into an IE page, then calling the rich jQuery API to select DOM elements. This would reduce the no. of lines in my AutoIt script drastically."

A basic set of tutorials is given below.

- Set text to a button
- Set text to an input text
- Submit a google search
- search Filtering by class for get only results urls

Reference: https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/81025-ie-automation-using-jquery/?do=findComment&comment=1058556

```
Global $objAppIE, $jQuery, $jQueryFilePath = @ScriptDir & '\jquery-1.9.1.js'
Global $oMyError = ObjEvent ( 'AutoIt.Error', '_MyErrFunc' )

If Not FileExists ( $jQueryFilePath ) Then InetGet ( 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js', $jQueryFilePath )
$objAppIE = ObjCreate ( 'InternetExplorer.Application' )
$objAppIE.visible = True
$objAppIE.navigate ( 'http://www.google.com/' )

$jQuery = _InsertJQuery ( $objAppIE )
If IsObj ( $jQuery ) Then
    $jQuery ( ':input[id="gbqfba"]' ).text ( 'Search With Bing' ) ; **set text button**
    Sleep ( 1000 ) ; just for see changes
    $jQuery ( ':input[id="gbqfq"]' ).val ( 'autoit' ) ; **set input text**
    Sleep ( 1000 ) ; just for see changes
    $jQuery ( ':input[id="gbqfba"]' ).submit ( ) ; submit
    _IEPageLoadWait ( $objAppIE )
    Do
        $aLinks = $jQuery ( '.l' ).get ( ) ; **filtering by class for get only results urls.**
    Until $aLinks.length
    ConsoleWrite ( '! Results Nb : ' & $aLinks.length & @Crlf )
    $i=0
    For $aLink In $aLinks
        $i+=1
        ConsoleWrite ( '+ ' & $i & ' $aLink.href : ' & $aLink.href & @Crlf )
    Next
EndIf

Func _InsertjQuery ( $objAppIE )
    Local $objWindow, $objHead, $objScript
    _IEPageLoadWait ( $objAppIE )
    If IsObj ( $objAppIE ) Then
        $objWindow = $objAppIE.document.parentWindow
        $objHead = $objAppIE.document.getElementsByTagName ( 'head' ).item ( 0 )
        If Not IsObj ( $objwindow.jQuery ) Then
            $objScript = $objAppIE.document.createElement ( 'script' )
            $objScript.type = 'text/javascript'
            $objScript.language = 'javascript'
            $objScript.defer = 'defer'
            $Script = FileRead ( $jQueryFilePath )
            $objScript.text = $Script
            $objHead.appendChild ( $objScript )
            While Not ( IsObj ( $objwindow.jQuery ) )
                Sleep ( 100 )
            WEnd
            $objwindow.jQuery.noConflict ( )
        EndIf
        Return $objwindow.jQuery
    EndIf
EndFunc ;==> _InsertjQuery ( )

Func _IEPageLoadWait ( $objAppIE )
    Do
        Sleep ( 50 )
    Until $objAppIE.readyState = 'complete' Or $objAppIE.readyState = 4
    Do
        Sleep ( 50 )
    Until $objAppIE.document.readyState = 'complete' Or $objAppIE.document.readyState = 4
    Do
        Sleep ( 50 )
    Until Not $objAppIE.busy
EndFunc ;==> _IEPageLoadWait ( )

Func _MyErrFunc ( )
    $HexNumber = Hex ( $oMyError.number, 8 )
    If $HexNumber = 80020006 Then Return
    Msgbox ( 0, '', 'We intercepted a COM Error !' & @CRLF & 'Number is: ' & $HexNumber & @CRLF & 'Windescription is: ' & $oMyError.windescription & @CRLF & 'Line Number: ' & $oMyError.scriptLine & @CRLF, 3 )
    Exit
Endfunc ;==> _MyErrFunc ( )
```